# RStudio y-axis label displays incomplete letters

Tags: r, rstudio

When I use base R to plot something, then certain characters will not be displayed correctly, e.g.

`plot(1:10,1:10, xlab = paste(letters[1:26], collapse =''), ylab = paste(letters[1:26], collapse =''))`

produces the following plot:

[image: erroneous character display on the y-axis]

Characters such as `h`, `n` and `u` are chopped off in the console view - however only on the y-axis. Exporting the plot via `png()` does not work, either. I have noticed that this problem only occurs when the code is executed in RStudio (Version 2022.07.0 Build 548, Windows 10).

Comment: Not reproducible on OSX 10.14.6, RStudio 2021.09.2 Build 382, R version 4.2.1.  May be version or OS specific.

Comment: It's not an issue on W11

Comment: Could this have to do with any settings in the IDE? I tried to change a couple of parameters already but nothing that seemed reasonable worked so far.